# Excel Conditional forward based on date older then

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-2013

I have this Excel document containg following data

```
(a1)Week No    (b1)Name    (c1)Save Untill    (d1)Description
    13             Name 1      2014-06-30         Description 1
    14             Name 2      2014-01-30         Description 2
    15             Name 3      2013-12-31         Description 3
    16             Name 4      2014-03-31         Description 4
    17             Name 5      2014-06-30         Description 5
```

The goal is

- To color the the row GREEN if the "save untill" date is more than 180
  days based on current date.
- To color the row RED if the "Save Untill" date is less than 180
  days based on current date.

I cant figure this out, hope you guys can help me out!

Regards
Niklas

Comment: well i donot know, i have googled some and i think i have to use som =if(e2<today(+180)) but i got formula error...

Comment: try `=E2-TODAY()>180`

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't put anything in `TODAY()`, because simply doing so will give you an error :) You can try `=TODAY(+180)` or `=TODAY(180)` and both would give you errors.

Comment: How come it dont update automatically? when i type in the formula it works but if i change the date it will be the same, nothin happen.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you would use the following applied to A2:D6 or whatever your full range is:

For red colored cells use:

```
=$C2<TODAY()+180
```

For green colored cells use:

```
=$C2>TODAY()+180
```

The absolute reference ($C2) allows the entire row to be highlighted that color instead of just the cell.